# Jacobian of a transformation in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, transformation

In an area called transformation optics, they transform Maxwell equations from one space coordinate system to another, and then somehow obtain the properties of background material $(\epsilon , \mu)$ in the first coordinate system, and this way find the required $(\epsilon , \mu)$ to direct EM waves in arbitrary directions.

From [this paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/42u4uuv51s4ja8x/TransformationEMTutorial_IEEEAntProp2010.pdf), we have a transformation defined in cylindrical coordinates as :
$$\rho'=R_1+\frac{R_2-R_1}{R_2}\rho$$
$$\phi'=\phi$$
$$z'=z$$

This transformation maps the circular region $0\leq\rho \leq R$ to the circular annular region $R_1\leq \rho' \leq R_2$. In the paper, the Jacobi matrix for this transformation is written as (equation 14):
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
(R_2-R_1)/R_2 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & \rho'/\rho & 0\\
 0& 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

We know that A is defined as
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial x'}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial x'}{\partial z}\\ 
\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial y'}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial y'}{\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial z'}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial z'}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial z'}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Why the element $A_{22}=\rho'/\rho$ instead of $1$?  This result is obtained [here](http://iopscience.iop.org/1367-2630/8/10/247/fulltext/), equation (11), using more accurate mathematical notation.

In another transformation, defined as:

$$\rho'=\rho$$
$$\phi'=\frac{a}{2l}(z+l)+\phi$$
$$z'=z$$
The matrix $A$ is obtained as:

$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1& \frac{a}{2l}\rho'\\
 0& 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

In this example, why the $A_{23}$ element is not $\frac{a}{2l}$?

Note: I think it has something to do with metric tensor, etc. that I don't understand.

Comment: i would also have said it had to be $1$. I think you are correct.

Comment: @Ale It must be correct. It's a step for obtaining the properties of a material (an engineering design), that after simulation works perfectly.

Comment: The only way of obtaining $\rho' / \rho$ is when $\phi$ is defined as $\phi' = \phi \rho' / \rho$ are you sure that it was really defined as you did? Could you maybe scan the part of the book where it evaluates the Jacobian matrix?

Comment: @Ale Yeah, sure. I added another example in the text that might be illuminating.

Comment: Take the second transformation and set $a=0$ you get the same transformation as above but the matrix has the element $A_{22} = 1$ I think that by definition of the Jacobian matrix this element must be $1$ and therefore there must be something wrong with the transformation in cylindrical coordinates of your first example if you say that the element $A_{22}$ must be $\rho' / \rho$

Comment: @Ale I think the two examples differ because of the definitions of $\rho$ and $\rho'$ in them.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the transformations are from cylindrical to cylindrical coordinates, and are purely linear in this representation. The coefficients in question must be $1$ and $\frac a{2l}$ as you say.

UPDATE:

As the coordinates are not Cartesian but curvilinear, differentiation isn't made the obvious way. There are scale factors to be taken into account. In the case of cylindrical coordinates, these are $1, \rho, 1$.

The corrected Jacobian is given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & \rho'& 0\\
 0& 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
[J]
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & \rho^{-1}& 0\\
 0& 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: The results I wrote in the question, are well-known and used regularly in transformation optics. See [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5466396&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D5466396) (if you have access), equation $(11)$ to $(14)$.

Comment: Do you really expect me to purchase the article ???

Comment: This is the downloadable link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/42u4uuv51s4ja8x/TransformationEMTutorial_IEEEAntProp2010.pdf

Comment: Thanks! But how is the above formula derived?

Comment: Read on curvilinear orthogonal coordinates.